# python.cannot import name 'TextBlob'

Tags: python, textblob

I was trying to import TextBlob into Python.

When I run the command directly inside shell, it works pretty well:
   from textblob import TextBlob

However, when I put it into the py file and run it, it doesn't work anymore, it says:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'TextBlob'
```

Please help me out with it, so desperate right now...Thanks a lot

Comment: While executing your .py file, have you checked that it is being done with the same python installation than when you call the Python IDLE or iPython where you can actually import it?

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem, solved it by deleting any file starting with test*, text* in the same folder.

Comment: My problem was that I had named my file textblob.py. Renaming it solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

1: The import should be: from textblob import TextBlob     (Python is case sensitive, so it's important to import TextBlob with with capital T & B)

2: textblob should be installed like this :
Python2:

> $ pip install -U textblob
>
> $ python -m textblob.download_corpora

Python3:

> $ pip3 install -U textblob
>
> $ python3 -m textblob.download_corpora

Comment: I had to do the above and my python file was named textblob.py which i had to rename to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do not have any file or folder named `text.py`.
It also won't works if any file or folder of your

Answer (score 1):

I think your project interpreter and the interpreter for the console, could be different. Make sure they are same.

Make sure TextBlob is installed in your project interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Pycharms on windows then you need to open pycharms as an administrator.

If you are installing it on Linux then sudo install the packages.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install textblob
```

on jupyter notebook

Answer (score -2):

I have install textblog by pip with the command :

```
sudo pip install textblob
```

And i have download the corpus with the command :

```
python -m textblob.download_corpora
```

And that works fine with the example of textblob website.

Here is the example that i run with the command : `./test.py`

just before i use `chmod +755 test.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def test():
    text = '''

    The titular threat of The Blob has always struck me as the ultimate movie
    monster: an insatiably hungry, amoeba-like mass able to penetrate
    virtually any safeguard, capable of--as a doomed doctor chillingly
    describes it--"assimilating flesh on contact.
    Snide comparisons to gelatin be damned, it's a concept with the most
    devastating of potential consequences, not unlike the grey goo scenario
    proposed by technological theorists fearful of
    artificial intelligence run rampant.
    '''

    blob = TextBlob(text)
    blob.tags           # [('The', 'DT'), ('titular', 'JJ'),
                        #  ('threat', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN'), ...]

    blob.noun_phrases   # WordList(['titular threat', 'blob',
                        #            'ultimate movie monster',
                        #            'amoeba-like mass', ...])

    for sentence in blob.sentences:
        print(sentence.sentiment.polarity)
    # 0.060
    # -0.341

    blob.translate(to="es")  # 'La amenaza titular de The Blob...'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from textblob import TextBlob
    test();
```

Comment: I followed all the instructions too, it works fine on another computer, but it doesn't work on mine... can't figure out why

Comment: what is your  [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) ?
write : echo $PYTHONPATH  .
Maybe you have a conflict in your python version.
that s why i prefere install Python Package with python-pip